# Download file with Tomcat servlet is downloaded incomplete

Tags: tomcat, servlets, download

I have a servlet that downloads files to the requested client. Now when the user request to download a xml file. It will start downloading and when it has finished the file look incomplete. It is missing some data at the end of the file.

My code looks like:

```
File file = new File(location);
response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=" + fileName);

FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();

byte[] outputByte = new byte[4096];
int length = -1;

//copy binary contect to output stream
while((length = fileIn.read(outputByte)) > 0)
{
    out.write(outputByte);
}

fileIn.close();
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Where is my code failing to download the full xml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your while loop like this. The buffer size is 4096. You should use only the length that is read in previous read().

```
  //copy binary contect to output stream
  while((length = fileIn.read(outputByte)) > 0)
  {
     fileOut.write(outputByte, 0, length);
  }
```

However, you should be using using [Guava ByteStreams](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) for this. You can find other libraries also supporting this.

Comment: can you please clarify why we have to use `write(byte[] b, int off, int len)` instead of `write(byte[] b)`. in [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(byte[])) it is mentioned that the general contract for write(b) is that it should have exactly the same effect as the call `write(b, 0, b.length)`.

Comment: Yes, both are same.